# Download so many tiny files without archiving?

Tags: java, download, tcp, archiving, udp

I want to implement a file server for a mobile app. This app requires so many tiny files to be downloaded from the server before it begins it's work And with updates from version to version some files are overwritten and some files gets modified or deleted.

Tried solutions:

1. Archive chunk download for each version, this means I create a zip file for each version and we serve the chunked zip file. The problem with this is that it's inefficient because extracting in the client requires too much extra space and second problem is that it's hard handling updates (downloading only necessary files when there are already some files on the client)
2. TCP download without archive, this one is inefficient because of too much overhead on TCP handshake for each file it wastes too much time
3. UDP download without archive, this one is not safe and we cannot guarantee the files downloaded on the client is healthy. Also doing checksum for each file on the client side is an expensive process we don't want to get into that.

Any suggestions is highly appreciated.

**Maybe it's woth mentioning that I use java spring boot on the server side**

Comment: Have you posted on stackoverflow? Programming and software development is offtopic here.

Comment: If you do post on stackoverflow, at least tell them *why* there are a shitload of tiny files, what they contain, and why they can't be combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Archive chunk download for each version, this means I create a zip file for each version and we serve the chunked zip file. The problem with this is that it's inefficient because extracting in the client requires too much extra space and second problem is that it's hard handling updates (downloading only necessary files when there are already some files on the client)

You are not required to use zip archives specifically. Many such systems (e.g. game launchers such as Steam or Battle.Net) use custom archive formats that are streamable, i.e. can be extracted without downloading the entire thing first, and usually support some form of patching. (Casync is one open-source example.)

It's possible that your platform *already* provides this feature, e.g. via "[Play Asset Delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery)" on Android.

> TCP download without archive, this one is inefficient because of too much overhead on TCP handshake for each file it wastes too much time

You don't need a separate TCP handshake for each file. Most file transfer protocols (other than the ancient FTP and AFS) have already solved this issue *very* long ago.

For example, HTTP/1.0 gained connection keep-alive support **in 1996** (with it becoming official in HTTP/1.1) and just about every HTTP client library you'll find will support connection reuse.

It's still one request *at a time* in HTTP/1.1, but the not-so-recent HTTP/2, with its multi-stream support, has been specifically designed to efficiently handle many concurrent requests at once (with tiled images being used as a popular demo).

Your mobile app probably already has an HTTP/2 client library in it. Make sure your server supports HTTP/2., then issue 100 async HTTP requests and let the library figure it out. (Also, don't host static assets from your Java app – host them from a separate web server designed to host static files.)

(Similarly, nearly all modern filesystem access protocols – SFTP, NFSv4, SMB – use a single long-lived TCP connection to process many requests. FTP and AFS are the only ones that don't.)

> UDP download without archive, this one is not safe and we cannot guarantee the files downloaded on the client is healthy.

You never use UDP directly – it's a foundation to build *transport protocols* on, which would provide the reliability you need. For example, HTTP/3 uses QUIC as its transport protocol, providing the same reliability as TCP would.

> Also doing checksum for each file on the client side is an expensive process we don't want to get into that.

It's not expensive compared to the actual download, and you're *already doing it anyway* if you use any kind of "secure" protocol – for example, with HTTPS, the TLS library will compute a MAC of every packet (which is more expensive than computing a plain hash).

Comment: Thank you for the hints, it helped a lot